# JSON dictionary with array values to C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, json, model-view-controller

I would like to know how to convert the following object to C# when reaching the mathod. I needed to create an object which can hold multiple array's within JSON something like the following

```
{   
    "cars": {
        "Ferrari":["LaFerrari","F40","458"],
        "Porsche":["911","959"],
        "Lamborghini":["Aventador"]
    }
}
```

The code I used is the following within cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtKey" />
            <input type="button" id="btnKey" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtChild" />
            <input type="button" id="btnChild" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
        $(function () {

            AddKeyToDictionary('Ferrari');
            AddKeyToDictionary('Porsche');
            AddKeyToDictionary('Lamborghini');

            AddValueToDictionary('Ferrari', 'LaFerrari');
            AddValueToDictionary('Ferrari', 'F40');
            AddValueToDictionary('Ferrari', '458');

            AddValueToDictionary('Porsche', '911');
            AddValueToDictionary('Porsche', '959');

            AddValueToDictionary('Lamborghini', 'Aventador');

            $('#btnKey').click(function () {
                AddKeyToDictionary($('#txtKey').val());
            });
            $('#btnChild').click(function () {
                AddValueToDictionary($('#txtKey').val(), $('#txtChild').val());
            });
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                submit();
            });

        });

        var dict = {};

        function AddKeyToDictionary(key) {
            dict[key] = [];
        }

        function AddValueToDictionary(key, value) {
            dict[key].push(value);
        }

        function submit() {

            var url = "@Url.Action("UpdateCustomFields", "Home")";

            var data = JSON.stringify({ 'cars': dict });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "Application/json;charset=utf-8",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (msg) {

                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    displayDialog("A communication Error has occurred, please contact IT support: " + error);
                }
            });
        }


    </script>

}
```

I've tried the following within MVC (got this from a JSON c# convertor)

```
public JsonResult UpdateCustomFields(RootObject cars)
        {
            return Json("");
        }

    }

    public class Cars
    {
        public List<string> Ferrari { get; set; }
        public List<string> Porsche { get; set; }
        public List<string> Lamborghini { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Cars cars { get; set; }
    }
```

The car makes should be dynamic and then the arrays below should be converted correctly.

I also tried to iterate through the array and changed them all to key value pairs which still wasn't rendering

```
function convertToKeyValue() {
   submitValue = [];

    for (var k in dict) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if (dict[k].length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dict[k].length; i++) {    
                    submitValue.push({ key: k, value: dict[k][i] });
                }
            } else {
                submitValue.push({ key: k, value: '' });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Passing them through the name/value pairs I was able to see them in the dynamic property within the controller but can't get to the variables.

```
public JsonResult UpdateClientCustomFields(object cars)
{    
    var result = customFields.XmlSerializeToString();

    return Json("hello");
}
```

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

**Updated:** I've had to convert the javascript array to a list of key pairs (not ideal) and use List> cars as the paramter, the model is not ideal, but will use this until I find a better way.

Here is the updated code

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit2" />

var submitValue = [];

function convertToKeyValue() {

    submitValue = [];

    for (var k in dict) {
        if (dict.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            //alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + dict[k]);
            //alert("KEY: " + k);

            if (dict[k].length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dict[k].length; i++) {
                    //alert("childrec: " + dict[k][i]);
                    submitValue.push({ key: k, value: dict[k][i] });
                }
            } else {
                submitValue.push({ key: k, value: '' });
            }
        }
    }

}

function submit2() {
    convertToKeyValue();

    var url = "@Url.Action("UpdateCustomFields2", "Home")";

    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'cars': submitValue });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "Application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {

        }
    });
}
```

MVC

```
public JsonResult UpdateCustomFields2(List<Dictionary<string, string>> cars)
{
    return Json("");
}
```

[image: Car Model]

Comment: In the future its best to avoid <code> tags with posted code in questions. They can cause weird formatting. Indenting lines of code by 4 spaces will produce well formatted code blocks. Good luck in solving your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `cars` property in `RootObject` to `public Dictionary<string,List<string>> cars {get; set;}`

Comment: HI ertdiddy, no luck, produces a null within the call.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code and updated the original post, this is the only way I can think of, expanding on your point, not the best way but something to work with until I find the best option

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your input param as string and then deserialize it to your object.

```
 public JsonResult UpdateCustomFields(string cars)
 {
     RootObject yourCars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(cars);

     return Json("");
 }
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, no luck, string is null.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, the following seems to work fine

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"
            {   
                ""cars"": {
                    ""Ferrari"":[""LaFerrari"",""F40"",""458""],
                    ""Porsche"":[""911"",""959""],
                    ""Lamborghini"":[""Aventador""]
                }
            }
        ";

        var dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which version of JSON.NET are you using? I remember older versions had issues with dictionaries, but you could probably just create your own converter if that is the case.

Comment: Hi, I think it is due to an older version, I've moved on with my solution at the moment, but will revisit and answer.